# How can I resolve the "Unique file URI" when using managed_file field in form API with a file name that already exists?

Tags: forms, ajax, 10

I am facing a strange issue with a managed_file field in my Drupal form API. Whenever I upload a file and save the form, and then come back again to upload another file with the same name, I get this error message.

> The specified file xyz.png could not be uploaded. The file temporary://xyz.png already exists. Enter a unique file URI.

However, if I try to upload the file again, it gets uploaded successfully with the file name renamed.

I noticed [a similar issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/filename_transliteration/issues/3247048) reported in the module issue queue.

Can anyone suggest why this might be happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I think you indicated that you have a custom code implementation. If you do we need to see that in order to answer your question.

Comment: Added my code here - https://github.com/zuhairkareem/form_api-test/ , this is multistep form, step 1 there is managed_file, file stored in temporary folder, Step2 - get name & emal, on Submit- move file from temporary folder to Public folder, I think the issue is due to moving from temporary folder to public folder in step 2.